# 457(b) - funding options

Tags: united-states, contribution, 457b

I'd like to put some money we saved towards my wife's Roth 475b.  Is it possible to just write a check from a personal account as a contribution or must is come out of her paycheck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paycheck.

If you want to go to the effort, increase your wife's contribution level **for a few paychecks**, and put the amount you *would* have sent to the 457b account into your checking account and "pretend" it's income.